# Multiple imageview on touch action listener

Tags: android, imageview, move, ontouchlistener

I have 4 views in the same activity. I want to move each Imageview on touch in whole screen, but it allow me to move in its width height.

Each image view's layout height and width is wrap_content.

It works fine with one image view with fill_parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its explained in [this](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/moving-views-part-2/) example.